# Select all MySQL records in the last day that are between a time range of 7am and midnight

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime

I have this query

```
SELECT * FROM `timeclock_timecard` 
WHERE `clock_in_datetime` > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

which can get record in the last day but I need to `limit` to records created after `7AM`

Any help please?

Comment: Have you tried playing with some functions in mysql .. Perhaps work with php `date()` function ...   https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Comment: 7 am is the cut? 6:59 you show yesterday's after 7:00 and on 7 the ones of the current day?

Comment: @maraca What I am doing is building a daily report from timeclock for all users so they clock in between 7-8am and out by 7-8pm so just trying to get a good number to ensure my report has only records for the current day

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * FROM `timeclock_timecard` 
WHERE `clock_in_datetime` > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY) 
and hour(`clock_in_datetime`) > 7;
```

Added one more filter condition to check for the `hour`.

Comment: Works good with exception I am having some issues on live data though, for some reason right now for 1 user who has 3 records that are returned with this query.  2 are from today which is good but 1 is from yesterday around the same time as the 2nd one from today.  See image for details http://i.imgur.com/6FuNiyc.png

Comment: This can't use an index, which seems a shame

Answer (score 1):

Your query was almost correct, because `CURDATE()` only gives the date you can just subtract 17 hours to get the correct result. [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2856d/2/0).

```
SELECT * FROM `timeclock_timecard` 
WHERE `clock_in_datetime` >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 17 HOUR)
```

To get the entries of the current day, we can add 7 hours (CURDATE() has time 0:00).

```
SELECT * FROM `timeclock_timecard` 
WHERE `clock_in_datetime` >= DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 HOUR)
```

Comment: This is great.  I am having some issues on live data though, for some reason right now for 1 user who has 3 records that are returned with this query.  2 are from today which is good but 1 is from yesterday around the same time as the 2nd one from today.  See image http://i.imgur.com/6FuNiyc.png

Comment: @JasonDavis yes, this depends when you plan to run the query, after midnight and before 7am the above version is good, after 8pm and before midnight you can add 7 hours instead of subtracting 17.

Comment: Any ideas how I could run it at anytime of the current day and have it only return records from the current day?

Comment: updated answer, one question remaining, probably doesn't matter, but do you count the hour from 0:00 to 1:00 which is 12PM to 1AM to "today" or "yesterday" (query would need change)?

Answer (score 0):

To get only rows from yesterday, with a time value of 7AM or later, we can add 7 hours to the expression.

If we only up until midnight of today (just rows from yesterday), we can add another condition, the datetime is less than midnight today.

For example:

```
SELECT t.*
  FROM `timeclock_timecard` t
 WHERE t.`clock_in_datetime` >= DATE(NOW()) + INTERVAL -1 DAY + INTERVAL 7 HOUR
   AND t.`clock_in_datetime` <  DATE(NOW())
```

If you want to exclude the exact 7:00:00 AM value, change the **`>=`** to just **`>`**.

---

FOLLOWUP

**Q:** *What I actually want is between about 5-6am TODAY and mindnight TODAY so anytime during today that I run the report for today I will get only timeclock data from users who clocked in/out today only and not include yesterdays data.*

**A:** The predicates are going to be of the form

```
 WHERE t.`clock_in_datetime` >=  expr1
   AND t.`clock_in_datetime` <   expr2
```

You just need to find the expressions `expr1` and `expr2` that return the appropriate datetime values.

Just use a simple SELECT statement to test:

```
 SELECT DATE(NOW()) + INTERVAL 5 HOUR  AS `start`
      , DATE(NOW()) + INTERVAL 1 DAY   AS `end`
```

**Q:** *I also modified my select to take in account my datetime is in* `UTC` *and my result needs to get todays records using* **local timezone**.

```
 SELECT * , CONVERT_TZ( clock_in_datetime , '+00:00', '-4:00' ) FROM `timeclock_timecard`
```

**A:** Personally, I would do the timezone conversion on the `exprN` values, not the column values. Having predicates on bare columns allows MySQL to make effective use of an index; wrapping the columns in expressions prevents MySQL from using an index.

If the MySQL system clock is UTC, and your datetime values stored in the table are in a different timezone, yes, use the MySQL `CONVERT_TZ` function.

Again, using a simple SELECT statement to develop and test the expressions:

```
 SELECT CONVERT_TZ( DATE(NOW()) + INTERVAL 5 HOUR, '+0:00', to_tz)   AS `start`
      , CONVERT_TZ( DATE(NOW()) + INTERVAL 1 DAY , '+0:00', to_tz)   AS `end`
```

Where **`to_tz`** is the timezone of the values in the table.

Once you get expressions `start` and `end` returning the values you need, then use those expressions in the predicates of the query of the timecard table.

Comment: What I actually want is between about 5-6am TODAY and mindnight TODAY so anytime during today that I run the report for today I will get only timeclock data from users who clocked in/out today only and not include yesterdays data.  All the solutions so far are  showing at least some data from the previews day.  I also modified my select to take in account my datetime is in UTC and my result needs to get todays records using local timezone `SELECT * , CONVERT_TZ(  clock_in_datetime ,  '+00:00', '-4:00' )  FROM timeclock_timecard`